# Apply CSS color to specific label based on its text

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change font color of a specific label. How to apply color depending or based on the text of that label.

I now that we can do:

```
SPAN.uh[title*="some_text"] 
{ color: white !important; }
```

Can we do something like this?

```
#errors > label[text*="NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE"]
{ color: LIME !important; }
```

EDIT:
That phrase "NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE" is on the stylish manager of the Stylish addon for Firefox, specifically:
chrome://stylish/content/edit.xul

How can I hide that phrase?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no content selector in CSS (at least at the moment).

Comment: As long as you have control over the content, the answer lies in your question: As Hashem sayd, there is no content selector, but you could define a `data-text` attribute containing the same content. Then you could match it using `[data-text*="..."]`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's selector engine has a selector for content, [**:contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), but native CSS does not.

`$('label:contains('some text')').css('color','Lime');` -  **[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gwqqn3mu/)**

Comment: harshly assuming you're using jquery, if not than disregard.

Comment: Is this solution not working for you in firefox?

Comment: That phrase "NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE" is on the stylish manager of the Stylish addon for Firefox. How can I hide that phrase?

Comment: You cant, the only option would be to narrow down a css selector for the element in which that text appears. My solution works for jQuery purposes, like I mentioned.. there isn't one for CSS/CSS3